# Difference between MongoSpringData id and _id

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoDB community edition 4.2 on Windows 10 and inserting some documents. My requirement is to store some documents containing 'id' as field name while MongoDB is replacing it with '_id' and making it the primary key. Is it possible to disable this feature and store key '_id' as the separate autogenerated primary key column and store 'id' as well in separated column which is part of my document?

We are using Spring Data MongoDb Repository entities insertion into MongoDb. What we have observerd the entity having name 'id' as primary key get converted to _id while entities having other name like projectId or something stored as it is with another seperate column as _id generated by MongoDB as primary key. Suggestions are helpful.

Code:

```java
@Autowired 
TrackHistoryRepository trackHistoryRepository;
    
trackHistoryRepository.save(entity);
    
public interface TrackHistoryRepository extends MongoRepository<OdataEntity, String> {}
```

Entity:

```java
public class CurrencyEntity implements OdataDeleteableEntity<Long> {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Mongo doesn't do that, SpringData does. Make your question and tags about *that* and show relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @deceze. My code is very generic  where I am saving data to mongoDb using MongoRepository<OdataEntity, String> as follows:

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can't do that. `_id` in mongodb is auto-incremented and auto-generated id key for specific record or data field. And `_id` is primary key by default set by mongodb. You can also enter your user defined key(value) to the `_id` but you cant change name of field.